# Cant Install expo cli

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to install Expo CLI for React Native
The latest version of Node js also installed

in command prompt, I typed `npm install expo-cli --global`

I'm getting error

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[..................] \ fetchMetadata: WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com
```

I also checked the [GitHub issues/3142](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142) but not found any solution

Comment: What is your npm version? You can check with `npm --version`.

Comment: Those look like warnings. Are you sure thst expo *failed* to install?

Comment: npm version    6.14.2 And Node Js version v13.10.1

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same issue install expo-cli with npm it gives WARN of request@2.88.2 deprecation, then what I did, simply install

```
 npm install -g yarn
```

and after that

```
 yarn global add expo-cli
```

and now it's successfully installed expo-cli, and I have the latest version of expo-cli as of today.

```
 $ expo --version
   3.15.4
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error, it is just a warning so you should not worry. Everything seems fine. You can check your expo-cli installation within below command:

```sh
$ expo --version
2.21.2
```

By the way you don't have to install expo-cli at all. You can use `npx expo init` to create a expo project.

Comment: 'expo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Can you add the entire output to your post after running the `npm install expo-cli --global` command?

Comment: I have the same issue -- there is no further output, I have let the command sit there for 20 minutes and it never continues past that warning. I've tried updating homebrew and node, but have the same issue again.

Comment: Thanks that's a nice tip, would still be nice to find out but likely it is an expo bug report needed, I see 2 users having the same thing on their github issues, and those are on windows. All posts seem to be from last 7 days, including here.

Comment: I'm not sure but try to disable Windows Search Service.

Comment: You can use WSL too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out my version of NodeJs was not supported. The documentation states that you need **Node.js LTS release or greater**.

This is the output when I attempted to install expo-cli then ran `expo --version`

Output:

```
ERROR: Node.js v12.10.0 is no longer supported.

expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:
* >=10.13.0 <11.0.0 (Maintenance LTS)
* >=12.13.0 <13.0.0 (Active LTS)
* >=14.0.0  <15.0.0 (Current Release)
```

I solved it by updating nodejs and reinstalled `expo-cli` with `npm i --global expo-cli` and it worked.